# liquibase default schema ignored in sql changelog

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, h2, liquibase

**Problem**: liquibase can't find table without setting schema in SQL script.

How to say liquibase use default schema in SQL changelog?

Before sql changelog, for adding check constraint, I create all table, without setting schema. Schema was set in application.properties and all table was created correctly in $RM_DB_SCHEMA.

```
RM_DB_SCHEMA: MANAGER
RM_DB_URL: "jdbc:h2:file:~/rmdb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${RM_DB_SCHEMA}"
RM_DB_USER: sa
RM_DB_PASSWORD: admin
RM_LB_USER: ${RM_DB_USER}
RM_LB_PASSWORD: ${RM_DB_PASSWORD}
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: ${RM_DB_SCHEMA}
      username: ${RM_DB_USER}
      password: ${RM_DB_PASSWORD}
      jdbc-url: ${RM_DB_URL}
  liquibase:
    change-log: "classpath:db/manager-changelog.xml"
    default-schema: ${RM_DB_SCHEMA}
    user: ${RM_LB_USER}
    password: ${RM_LB_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    database: postgresql
```

Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set changelog.xml::d::d:
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Таблица "STATUS" не найдена
Table "STATUS" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CONSTRAINT STATUS_ID CHECK (exists (SELECT 1 FROM STATUS s WHERE STATUS_ID = s.id)) [42102-200] [Failed SQL: (42102) ALTER TABLE TEST ADD CONSTRAINT STATUS_ID CHECK (exists (SELECT 1 FROM STATUS s WHERE STATUS_ID = s.id))]

Comment: I found one solution: using ${database.defaultSchemaName} in SQL.
But I don't really like it. Why I should add the schema if the same script works on executing script in db manualy

Comment: As far as I know, the liquibase "default schema" is only used to define the schema where `databasechangelog` is created. It doesn't affect the schema for your own tables. If you want to change that, you could have an unconditional `set search_path = ...` before anything else. Or even change the search_path of the user.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you are using h2 or Postgres? You certainly can not create a check constraint in Postgres that uses a query (which looks like you are trying to do a foreign key check - then why not define a proper foreign key to begin with)

Comment: actually constraint check a little bit trickier, here is just example. And FK is not appropriate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, I can't use subquery in check in postgresql. It was helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution.
The problem was in local developing with h2. (it always init as public schema). I'm just adding SET SCHEMA after creating it.

in test properties:

```
jdbc-url: 'jdbc:h2:file:~/rmdb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ${application.database.schema}\;SET SCHEMA ${application.database.schema}'
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy one to fix this, is to use the property: `database.defaultSchemaName`.

You can write to your sql statement like this:

```
<sql>UPDATE ${database.defaultSchemaName}.product SET ...</sql>
```